# Finding the optimal probabilty distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, histograms

I am trying to obtain the optimal probability distribution function to the following [data](http://www.mediafire.com/file/g62mq888cay7b66/data_prob_new.dat/file).

My attempt:

```
data = Import["data_prob_new.dat", "Table"];
P00 = Histogram[Flatten[data], Automatic, "Probability", 
ChartStyle -> Gray, ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[None], 
ImageSize -> 500]
fit = FindDistributionParameters[Flatten[data], 
LaplaceDistribution[a, b]]; 
a0 = a /. fit[[1]];
b0 = b /. fit[[2]];
lim = 1000;
t0 = Plot[PDF[LaplaceDistribution[a0, b0], x], {x, a0, lim}, 
PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}, PlotRange -> All];
P0 = Show[{P00, t0}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
FrameStyle -> Thick, PlotRange -> {{0, All}, {-0.001, All}}, 
PlotRangePadding -> 0, PlotRangeClipping -> True]
```

[image]

As we can see, the Laplace probability distribution fails to smoothly fit the tail of the histogram. My question: How can we obtain the best fit (type of distribution) for this histogram?

Comment: The data are not distributed Laplace.

Comment: EmpiricalDistribution? https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EmpiricalDistribution.html

Comment: Gamma distribution might be better

Comment: Try using the EstimatedDistribution function, with a range of PDFs. Looks a bit like the exponential distribution to me.

Comment: There is no "optimal" because you haven't stated what kind of process generated the data.  You just have data for which you'd like a reasonable and more compact description such as "Exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$".  Also, you want "PDF" rather than "Probability" to make the histogram and probability density match in scale.

Comment: @JimB Exactly! Could you please present how could I obtain an exponential fit to the histogram?

Comment: @mikado gave you what is likely the best answer:  Fit a gamma distribution `GammaDistribution[\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma], \[Mu]]`.  (I only used "Exponential distribution" as a specific - but not necessarily desired - example.)

Comment: @JimB I have already tried it but the fit is no good, same as the Laplace.

Comment: "no good" ????  See answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that you just have data and an urge to fit a parametric probability distribution, the quality of the fit is in the eye of the beholder.  Here's the fit with the gamma distribution (suggested by @mikado) (which I think you'll be hard-pressed to find a better fit):

```
P00 = Histogram[data, Automatic, "PDF", ChartStyle -> Gray, 
   ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[None], ImageSize -> 500, 
   PlotRange -> All];
fit = FindDistributionParameters[data, 
   GammaDistribution[α, β, γ, μ]];

t0 = Plot[PDF[GammaDistribution[α, β, γ, μ] /. fit, x], {x, μ0, Max[data]},
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 100];
P0 = Show[{P00, t0}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, FrameStyle -> Thick,
  PlotRange -> {{0, All}, {0, All}}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, PlotRangeClipping -> True]
```

[image: Histogram and fit with gamma distribution]

Comment: Just a comment: Inside the `Histogram[...]` you changed the option from "Probability" to "PDF". Why? What if we want to plot probability instead of PDF and find the best fit of it?

Comment: You were estimating the parameters of a probability distribution function (pdf) and using the `PDF` function to display the probability distribution function.  For a histogram to match scales, you need the "PDF" option.  About the second question I answer with a question:  Why would you want a probability scale that's associated with an arbitrary sample size and arbitrary layout of the bins?